# can I like fan page with application?

Tags: php, facebook

My question is if I can like a fan page with some graph api or something else? 
here is my code:

```
$facebook->api('[fanpage_id]/likes', 'post', 
array('access_token' => 'my_token'));
```

and if I can do it by javascript SDK without the likebox?
also I gave the publish_stream permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Likes can only be registered and submitted via the like button.